# Reporting significance level in corrplot()

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I'm currently using `corrplot()` from the `corrplot` package in R and I've stumbled across two problems. For simplicity, I'll use the same notation as the help/introduction page for corrplot.

1. I'd like to inscribe either my p-value or how significant the test was (or both!) in all cells, not just the insignificant ones.
2. I'd like these inscriptions only in the upper triangular.

To address 2) first, I've been able to use this, but if feels kind of hacky:

```
corrplot(M, type="upper", p.mat = res1[[1]], insig="p-value", tl.pos="n")
corrplot(M, type="lower", add=T, tl.pos="d", cl.pos="n"))
```

However I haven't been able to figure out number 1. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: You can add `sig.level=0` to the first plot

Comment: While technically that works, corrplot() rounds to two decimal places, so it doesn't show precision. It would be more useful to have some kind of indication for how small the p-value is.

Comment: So you would like to add, for example`"<0.0001"` or similar? I think this will be easier to do by adding a format to the pvalue matrix and then plotting using `text`.

Comment: Sure, something similar to that would work. Perhaps asterisks denoting significance or something along those lines. It seems like such a pain to input them manually with the text function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick way is to add `sig.level=0` to the first plot, so all p-values are shown (actually, due to numerical precision some p-values will be exactly zero, so you may need to set it to `sig.level=-0.1`, for example)

```
require(corrplot)

# Data
M <- mtcars[3:7]
pval <- psych::corr.test(M, adjust="none")$p

# Corrplot
corrplot(cor(M), type="upper", p.mat=pval, insig="p-value", 
                                               tl.pos="n", sig.level=0)
corrplot(cor(M), type="lower", add=T, tl.pos="d", cl.pos="n")
```

This gives

[image]

However, if you want to add more detail to the p values it is probably easier to post-format the plot and add them using a `text` call

```
# Plot
corrplot(cor(M), type="upper", tl.pos="n")

# Get positions & plot formatted p-values
pos <- expand.grid(1:ncol(pval), ncol(pval):1)
text(pos, p_format(pval))

# lower tri
corrplot(cor(M), type="lower", add=T, tl.pos="d", cl.pos="n")
```

To give

[image]

Format function

```
p_format <- function(x, ndp=3)
{
  out <- format(round(as.numeric(x),ndp),ns=ndp,scientific=F,just="none")
  ifelse(out=="0.000","<0.0001", out)
}
```

My view (fwiw) is that this is adding too much info to the plot