# Two different p-values for one variable combination? corrplot::corrplot

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, r-corrplot

I woult like to corrplot my data (the package I use, surprise surprise, is {corrplot}) and display the p-values of the pairwise correlations in it.

Now I found some useful stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709204/reporting-significance-level-in-corrplot) on how to do exactly that and at first glance, it went surprisingly well. But then I noticed that the p-values were completely strange and they didn't correspond to the actual p-values from cor.test().

I already found out (using exemplary data) that it's not due to my data, but something I got wrong about the code with which I'm trying to include the p-values.

So here's a reproducible example:

```
#using built-in r-data:
data("mtcars")

#now for the corrplot:
M = cor(mtcars, use="complete.obs")
pval <- corr.test(M, adjust="none")$p
corrplot(M, method = "color", type = "upper", 
     order = "original", tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45,
     family="serif", p.mat=pval, insig="p-value", sig.level=0)
```

This is what I get:

[(didn't let me upload the file, so you have to click the link...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyB3O.png)

Anyway, to illustrate that these are not the actual p-values, let's take juts one pair, namely "qsec" and "drat":

```
cor.test(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$drat, use="complete.obs")
```

And the resulting p-value ("p-value = 0.6196") is definitely not the one you see in the corrplot ("0.14").

This is probably really stupid and I'm sure (p<.0001) that I'm overlooking something - but I don't know what it is. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `corr.test(M, adjust="none")` you're passing the matrix `M` into the function. And matrix `M` is something different than the data you have. Try to use `corr.test(mtcars, adjust="none")` instead. You need to pass your actual dataset and not a matrix of correlations.

If you check how `data.frame(M)` looks like you'll see that your `drat` variable has 11 values and those are the correlations of `drat` and the rest of the variables. However, you want `drat` to be the `drat` column from `mtcars` with 32 values.

You can pass the correlation matrix `M` to the `corrplot` function, but not in the `corr.test` function.

Comment: OK that makes sense, but how can I get the p-values from the simple `corr.test(mtcars)` function into my corrplot? I guess by `pvals <- corr.test(mtcars, adjust="none")`?

Comment: Yes, no need to change anything else.

Comment: UPDATE: It worked perfectly. Thank you, @AntoniosK. :)

Comment: However, I'm still not sure why one would need to extract the p-values of M as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709204/reporting-significance-level-in-corrplot

Comment: Always check what each function expects as an input. I think a good way to remember is that a plot (like `corrplot`) just cares about plotting some values, but a -statistical- test (like `corr.test`) needs the actual observations.

Comment: Because the plot only cares about plotting some info that you'll pass to it. It cannot calculate the p values for you as it will never see your actual data. That's why you have to calculate the p values in advance (using a statistical test) and then just use those in the plot.

Comment: Another useful method is this: https://rdrr.io/cran/PerformanceAnalytics/man/chart.Correlation.html . Just in case you haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Right, I understand that. Now I calculated the p-values based on `mtcars` instead of `M`. But why then would anyone care about the p-values based on `M` is what I was asking myself. This is more like a theoretical question of what makes sense and what doesn't rather than a technical question that addresses how `corrplot` works.

Comment: Thanks for the link. `chart.correlation` seems even cooler than `corrplot` (in terms of the amount of information you can pack into a single graph). I'll definitely make use of that in the future...

Comment: In the example in the link you sent the way they define `M` is different than yours. Your `M` is a matrix of correlations, but the `M` in the link is a part of the actual data `M <- mtcars[3:7]`.

Comment: OK I guess I should have looked more carefully. Thanks again! ;)