# Unused argument - corrplot?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am a novice at this. I wanted to create a correlation matrix using corrplot and used the following code:

```
 cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
        }
    }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
  p.mat
}

        p.mat<-cor.mtest(dataset)

    corrplot(cor(dataset, use="complete.obs"), type="upper", order="hclust", 

    p.mat=p.mat, sig.level=0.1)
```

It's one I used before, but this time around I got an error message:

```
Error in corrplot(cor(dataset, use = "complete.obs"), type = "upper",  : 
  unused arguments (type = "upper", order = "hclust", p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.01)
```

Any idea why that is and how I can fix it?

Comment: If i substitute `mtcars` for `dataset` then it runs as expected and I cannot reproduce the error. ps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709204/reporting-significance-level-in-corrplot/29710462#29710462) shows an approach with less code (but extra package) to get the pvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `unused argument` error in R means that you are providing named arguments that do not match to the actual arguments of the function. This is generally caused by misspellings or accidental usage of similarly-named functions from different packages.

It looks like the arguments being flagged in this case are for the `corrplot` function of the `corrplot` package. There are other `corrplot` functions from other packages, e.g. `arm`. Are you sure you loaded the right package?

Comment: Yes solved the problem. Seems I had another package loaded w/ a command same as the name of the dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(corrplot)

dat = read.csv('yourdata')

M<- cor(t(dat[,-1]), use="complete.obs", method="pearson")
corr <- round(cor(M),1)

corrplot(corr , method = "color",is.corr = FALSE
         ,order = "hclust",hclust.method = c("complete"))
```